# Trouble installing @angular/google-maps on angular13

Tags: angular, npm, angular-google-maps

when I tried installing it shows

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: map-acclerator@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/google-maps@14.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm ERR!   @angular/google-maps@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

even if I use --force or --legacy-peer-deps

I get an error while importing it in app.module.ts

Comment: Did you just run the command `npm i @angular/google-maps`?

Comment: The latest version of `@angular/google-maps` is version 14, which will be compatible with Angular 14 and above. You need to install the version that’s compatible with Angular 13. `npm i @angular/google-maps@13.3.9`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install an older version of the google-maps package since it requires at least angular 14. The last version that supported angular 13 was 13.3.9.  You can install it like this:

```
 npm i @angular/google-maps@13.3.9
```